# Assigning multiple Values to a hash Reference - Array

Tags: perl

i declared the following sub (In reality, the values come out of the Database - so i simplified it):

```
sub get_date {
 my ($ref_last)=@_;
 $$ref_last->{duration}='24,0,4';
 ($$ref_last->{duration}->{d},
  $$ref_last->{duration}->{h},
  $$ref_last->{duration}->{m})
   = split(/\,/, $$ref_last->{duration});
}
```

This sub is called from the main-Part of the script, like this:

```
my $hashy;
get_date(\$hashy);
print $hashy->{duration}->{d};
```

Everything ist fine, and works like a charm, until i use strict:

```
use strict;
my $hashy;
get_date(\$hashy);
print $hashy->{duration}->{d};
```

in this case perl says "*Can't use string ("24,0,4") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use*"

I already tried `ref($ref_last)` - but `ref` is a read-only function.

Any suggestions, why this happens - and perhaps a better solution ?

Here's the full (non)-Working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $hashy;
get_date(\$hashy);
print $hashy->{duration}->{d};

sub get_date {
        my ($ref_last)=@_;
        $$ref_last->{duration}='24,0,4';
        ($$ref_last->{duration}->{d},
         $$ref_last->{duration}->{h},
         $$ref_last->{duration}->{m})
                = split(/\,/, $$ref_last->{duration});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, you're trying to change the format of an existing hash value (from «`24,0,4`» to «`{ d=>24, h=>0, m=>4 }`»). Here's how I'd do it.

```
sub split_duration {  # Changes in-place.
    my ($duration) = @_;
    my %split;
    @split{qw( d h m )} = split(/,/, $duration);
    $_[0] = \%split;
}

my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
split_duration( $row->{duration} );
```

or

```
sub split_duration {
    my ($duration) = @_;
    my %split;
    @split{qw( d h m )} = split(/,/, $duration);
    return \%split;
}

my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
$row->{duration} = split_duration( $row->{duration} );
```

Explanation of the problem and initial solutions below.

---

Without strict, `24,0,4` was treated as a hash reference, which means Perl was creating a variable named `$24,0,4`!!! That's bad, which is why `use strict 'refs';` prevents it.

The underlying problem is your attempt to assign two values to `$$ref_last->{duration}`: a string

```
'24,0,4'
```

and a reference to a hash

```
 { d => 24, h => 0, m => 4 }
```

It can't hold both. You need to rearrange your data.

I suspect you don't actually use `24,0,4` after you split it, so you could fix the code as follows:

```
sub get_date {
    my ($ref_last)=@_;
    my $duration = '24,0,4';
    @{ $$ref_last->{duration} }{qw( d h m )} =
        split(/,/, $duration);
}
```

If you need `24,0,4`, you can reconstruct it. Or maybe, you can store the combined duration along with d,h,m.

```
sub get_date {
    my ($ref_last)=@_;
    my $duration = '24,0,4';
    $$ref_last->{duration}{full} = $duration;
    @{ $$ref_last->{duration} }{qw( d h m )} =
        split(/,/, $duration);
}
```

Or in a separate elements of the higher up hash.

```
sub get_date {
    my ($ref_last)=@_;
    my $duration = '24,0,4';
    $$ref_last->{full_duration} = $duration;
    @{ $$ref_last->{duration} }{qw( d h m )} =
        split(/,/, $duration);
}
```

Comment: The interface of this sub seems bad to me too, but not knowing its actual purpose, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, $ref_hash->{duration} comes out of a `$sth->fetchrow_hashref()` - Don't want to split it in 3 extravalues in the sql. is there anyway to "delete" `$ref_hash->{duration}` (but not the whole hash) after / before assigning it to the subvals (d,h,m) ?

Comment: Got it ... simply selected the field "duration" as "duration_pre" and then filled duration->h,m,d with your solution ... Many thanks !!

Comment: @int2000, `my %split; @split{qw( d h m )} = split(/,/, $$ref_last->{duration}); $$ref_last->{duration} = \%split;`

Answer (score 2):

Inside `get_date`, you assign a string to `$ref_last->{duration}` but then attempt to access it like a hashref. You also have extra dollar signs that attempt to dereference individual values plucked from the hash.

I would write it as

```
sub get_date {
  my($ref_last) = @_;
  my $duration = '24,0,4';
  @{ $ref_last->{duration} }{qw/ d h m /} = split /\,/, $duration;
}
```

The last line is a [*hash slice*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) that allows you to assign values to the `d`, `h`, and `m` keys in a single list-assignment.

In the context of the caller, you need to set up a bit of scaffolding.

```
my $hashy = {};
get_date($hashy);
```

Without initializing `$hashy` to contain a new empty hashref, `get_date` does all its assignments and then throws away newly-built edifice. This is because when you copy parameters out of `@_`, you are using pass-by-value semantics.

Perl will accommodate pass-by-reference as well. Perl has a feature known as [*autovivification*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification) where the language builds necessary scaffolding for you on demand. To use that style, you would write

```
my $hashy;
get_date($hashy);

sub get_date {
  my($ref_last) = @_;
  my $duration = '24,0,4';
  @{ $_[0]->{duration} }{qw/ d h m /} = split(/\,/, $duration);
}
```

Note the use of `$_[0]` to directly access the first parameter, which is an *alias* to `$hashy` in this case. That is, `get_date` modifies `$hashy` directly.

Either way, say we print the contents with

```
print "[", join("][" => %{ $hashy->{duration} }), "]\n";
```

in which case the output is some permutation of

```
[h][0][m][4][d][24]
```

Building complex data structures with Perl isn’t difficult, but you have to learn the rules.

- [Perl references and nested data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), `man perlref`
- [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), `perldoc perldsc`
- [Manipulating Arrays of Arrays in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html), `perldoc perllol`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a weird syntax for your hash reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $hashref = {};
get_date($hashref);

print $hashref->{duration}->{d};

sub get_date {
    my ($ref_last) = @_;
    $tmp = '24,0,4';

    ($ref_last->{duration}->{d},
     $ref_last->{duration}->{h},
     $ref_last->{duration}->{m})
            = split(/,/, $tmp);
}
```

and in your subroutine use `$ref_last->{duration}`, without `$$`.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow you. Could you please give a complete working example ? I learned: If i have to return values from a sub (without `return $returnvar`), i have to pass them as Reference (`\$var`). To dereference it, i use `$$var` in the sub. That works fine, until i `use strict`.

Comment: By doing that change, `$hashref` will not get autovivified, so it will remain undef after `get_date` is called. He would need to do `my $hashref = {};`

Comment: @ikegami, it seems it's smth special related to `split`; even with `my $hashref = {};` the same error arise; if using a simple variable like in your answer, it works fine, but if a hash element is used, it falls

Comment: @ArtM, My `my $hashref = {};` comment was regarding the change in calling convention you made. It wasn't meant to solve the problem the OP asked about.

Comment: yes, it seems I had a bad day and I'm completly out of the subject and even wrongly read erronous line numbers when I was *playing* with this example :/ ... better if I'll not post nonsense